# Manipulating array to add through setData on highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have the following data:

```
var data = {"categories":["GLA Age: 65+"],"series":[{"name":"Hendon","data":[11.98]},{"name":"High Barnet","data":[17.86]},{"name":"Mill Hill","data":[13.73]},{"name":"Oakleigh","data":[17.42]},{"name":"Totteridge","data":[17.76]}]};
```

I need the 'names' to be the categories names so I'm using 'events > load' to apply this to the highcharts code:

```
var seriesData = this.series;
var tCategories = [];
for (i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
    tCategories.push(seriesData[i].name);
}
this.xAxis[0].setCategories(tCategories);
```

Then I need to set the 'data' into one array like

```
[11.98, 17.86, 13.73, 17.42, 17.76]
```

The problem I've come across is that the first lot of data shows in the first bar:

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/13rexxyo/3/

The code to create the new array ([11.98, 17.86, 13.73, 17.42, 17.76])

```
var arrayofArrays = data.series.map(function (item) {
     return JSON.stringify([item.data]);
});

    var seriesString = arrayofArrays;
    seriesString = seriesString;
    var n = JSON.stringify(seriesString).replace(/\[|]|"/g, '');
    var g = '[' + n + ']';
    var h = JSON.stringify(g);

    var seriesC = JSON && JSON.parse(g) || $.parseJSON(g);

    this.series[0].setData(seriesC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's being over-complicated, if I understand correctly (though your desired outcome is not entirely clear).

You can loop through the JSON and return a data array easily enough without using `stringify` or anything like that, and without needing a load event:

**Code:**

```
var title = rawData.categories[0];
var chartData = []
$.each(rawData.series, function(i, node) {
  chartData.push({ 'name': node.name, 'y': node.data[0] })
});
```

And then:

```
series: [{
    data: chartData
}]
```

**Updated fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/13rexxyo/5/

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]